# Which Twilio .Net helper library for new project

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, twilio

As a Twilio newbee coding in C# I am confused by the range of .Net helper libraries authored by Twilio Inc, my confusion is further compounded by online tutorials that show different helper API usage to solve a common problem.

My hunch is that after an extended Release Candidate phase the Twilio-csharp package on Nuget dated 14th February 2017 and described as 5.0.0-rca4, is the version to base my new development on. I think this corresponds to the twilio-csharp Next-Gen-2 branch on GitHub.

My development requirement is modest:

1. Raise an outbound voice call in an Azure Function().
2. Capture the call connect event in an Azure WebApi controller and
   reply with a say & gather XML instruction.
3. Log the DTFM digits entered in a database hosted on azure via another
   WebApi entry point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

My suggestion is to use the (now GA'ed) version 5 package as it contains API changes compared to the older packages and also introduces .NET Standard 1.4 compatibility.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you I went down the RC route but hit a new problem. The v5.0 RC library now incorporates the TwiML namespace but not Twilio MVC support. The older separate Twilio MVC package has a dependency on the older stand-alone TwiML package, so now the Visual Studio compiler is complaining about an ambiguous reference to the TwiML.Gather class. I don't see a v5.0 compatible version of Twilio MVC on Nuget.

Comment: @camelCase you're looking for this: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-aspnet

Comment: Also, @camelCase, I'm not sure MVC support will help you if you are using WebApi?

Comment: @dprothero The twilio-aspnet library did indeed solve the multiple TwiML namespace includes. I had missed this project, it must be very new with just 14 Nuget downloads.

Comment: @dprothero I thought I should report that the inbound voice controller example on the Twilio.aspnet Github homepage would not compile until I downloaded and compiled the Twilio.aspnet.common project.

Comment: Sorry about that @camelCase - I've uploaded a fix for that: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Twilio.AspNet.Mvc/5.0.1 - If you find any other issues or have requests, feel free to report them on the GitHub repo.